Cannot compile when ItemsSource nests another datatemplate
I am trying to run this code:
<cards:CarouselView >
    <cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
       <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
            <StackLayout>
                <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewContent}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Hi yolonese"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </x:Array>
    </cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
</cards:CarouselView>

I got this card:Carouselview to work, but only when I use hardcoded layouts without any binding inside of it:
<cards:CarouselView >
    <cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
       <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Hi my guy"/>
                <Button Text="test"/>
            </StackLayout>
            
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Hi yolonese"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </x:Array>
    </cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
</cards:CarouselView>

As soon as I create a collection view that actually binds to layouts (as in the first example) It doesn't even compile stating "Value cannot be null" 4 times coming from basically no where.
So I am assuming it fails because I use another DataTeamplateSelector inside another items template.
If I just left out the <Grid> part of the first code from:
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid>

   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

It does compile; but as soon as something is inside this datatemplate it doesnt compile anymore.
Any tips on why this might be and how I could circumvent that?
UPDATE:
I tried giving the template a specific datatype:
 <cards:CarouselView >
     <cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
         <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
             <StackLayout>
                 <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewContent}">
                     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:CollectionViewContent">
                             <Grid Padding="10,6,10,6">
                                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                     <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                                     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                 <Label TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Default=Black}" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
                                 <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black, Default=White}"/>
                                 <Label Margin="0,5,0,5" TextColor="{Binding Color}" FontFamily="WuerthExtraBold" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding PropertyValue}"/>
                             </Grid>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 </CollectionView>
             </StackLayout>
             <StackLayout>
                 <Label Text="Hi yolonese"/>
             </StackLayout>
         </x:Array>
     </cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
 </cards:CarouselView>

which just leaves me with the same errors.

Have you tried to add x:DataType for the DataTemplate of the CollectionView?

No, can you show me an example?

Please have a look at my update

1.May I know what is cards:CarouselView?2. This issue seems to related with:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/13495#discussioncomment-5082411, you can refer to it.
